# How to update one fragment from another in view pager android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager that has two different fragments.

```
 switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return LineChartOdoFragment.newInstance(msg, list, text, vehiclelist);
            case 1:
                return OdoTotalKmsFragment.newInstance(text, list, vehName, false, new OdoTotalKmsFragment.Updateable() {
                    @Override
                    public void update(TextView total_kms, TextView vehicle_name, RecyclerView odo_recycler) {

                        int total = 0;

                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                            total = total + (Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).getKms()) / 1000);
                        }

                        total_kms.setText("" + total);
                        vehicle_name.setText(vehName);

                        OdoKmsAdapter adapter = new OdoKmsAdapter(getActivity(), list);
                        odo_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                        odo_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }
                });
            default:
                return LineChartOdoFragment.newInstance(msg, list, text, vehiclelist);
        }
```

Now the first fragment has a spinner and it is updated when different items are selected.

What i am looking for is when the values are updated in first fragment the second one should get updated too. (I have also set an interface in the second one.)

But the second one never updates and retains the previous values.

How do i update both fragmnets?

The first fragment calls an async task and the the handler updates both fragments.

```
 private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //myMessage.arg1
        //1 - Home page data




         if (msg.arg1 == 7) {

            odoReadingsModelList = (ArrayList) msg.obj;




            no_result_odo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lineChart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lineChartOdo = new LineChartOdo(odoReadingsModelList, lineChart, context);
            lineChartOdo.createLineChartOdo();


  //updating second fragment
             OdoTotalKmsFragment.newInstance("", odoReadingsModelList, vehName, true, new OdoTotalKmsFragment.Updateable() {
                 @Override
                 public void update(TextView total_kms, TextView vehicle_name, RecyclerView odo_recycler) {

                     Log.e("LineChart Odo ", "Updating");

                     int total=0;

                     for (int i = 0; i < odoReadingsModelList.size(); i++) {
                         total = total + (Integer.parseInt(odoReadingsModelList.get(i).getKms()) / 1000);
                     }

                     total_kms.setText(""+total);
                     vehicle_name.setText(vehName);

                     OdoKmsAdapter adapter = new OdoKmsAdapter(getActivity(), odoReadingsModelList);
                     odo_recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                     odo_recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                 }
             });





        } else if (msg.arg1 == 8) {

            String res = msg.obj.toString();



            lineChart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_result_odo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_result_odo.setText("" + res);


        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to pass data from 1 fragment to other.

Complete example from EventBus repo:

**EventBus in 3 steps**

Define events:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

Prepare subscribers: Declare and annotate your subscribing method, optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register and unregister your subscriber. For example on Android, activities and fragments should usually register according to their life cycle:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Post events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

for detailed info read example on EventBus repo on github at this [link](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

if you dont want to use third party library then use this method
To update 1 fragment from another you can create Interface as a Callback, and implement in your Activity and 2nd Fragment. Then you can pass data from 1 fragment to other.

Comment: i have created an interface. The handler from second fragment call the new instance of second fragment again

Answer (score -1):

I think `OdoTotalKmsFragment.newInstance()` will always give you a new object of `OdoTotalKmsFragment`, you should save the instance as a member, then update this member instance.